# Grid -Component Layout is missing in Presentation Details of Standard values

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

I am using Sitecore 9.1.1 with SXA 1.81.

I need to set the Grid- Component Layout in the presentation details for my template standard values, but I am seeing the Component Layout as blank

[image: Pre]

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Standard Values for presentation when working with SXA. This is not how you should work. In SXA you should go with Page and Partial designs. For more details, take a look here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/designing.html.

There are more things which won't work on the Standard Values as there is no site context. Most of the SXA features need site context to work.

Comment: Hi @DawidRutkowski, yep we have avoided using standard values but our project demands certain pages that won't be working as per the SXA standards - partial and pages designs. And the scenario is we have multiple page items created using that non-SXA page and we need to set the grid for those, so any alternative solution should help.

Comment: There is no alternative solution. If you want to use SXA features, you need to be in the SXA site context.

Comment: We somehow managed to resolve that. Thanks, though!